# Deserialize from json to one of a number of types, then handle that new object

Tags: c#, deserialization, handle

I am thinking of something and I am not sure what direction to go.
The basic situation is I will have a class serialised to JSON in a database.

I want to retrieve the string and create an object. however I don't know what the type in the database is.

I will know what possible type it could be (say all types in a particular namespace)

My Psuedo plan is to retrieve the string and attempt to deserialize it to each type (using Dependency injection to retrieve possible types?)

If I manage to deserialize to a particular type then hand off the new object to a specific Handle that knows about that type.

Is this something that is commonly done, and is there examples I could look at?

Comment: Deserialize to an object, try to cast the object to your known types until one doesn't throw an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you store the object type in a separate database column?

With that you can deserialize by type.

Answer (score 1):

You can first load to JObject and then, looking for some properties, you can cast to correct type.

```
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);

if (jobj["SomeProp"] != null)
{
    var someClass = jobj.ToObject<SomeClass>();
}
```